# NetSuite Script : Is there a way creating a Payment on Account record for Supplier/Vendor without associating it with a bill

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, restlet

Could someone please explain if it's possible to create a vendor payment record via script without associating it with a bill, whether using SuiteScript or RESTlet?

I'm planning to develop the script based on your advice.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `record.Type.VENDOR_PREPAYMENT` instead of `record.Type.VENDOR_PAYMENT`.

See [Vendor Prepayment](https://suiteanswers.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/91319/loc/en_US) for information on Vendor Prepayments, and [Vendor Prepayments Setup](https://suiteanswers.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/87403/loc/en_US) for information on setting your account up for this.  There are several prerequisites, including enabling the feature, before it is available in the account.

Comment: Thank you, I can create vendor prepayment, however, this doesn't reflect in the Aged Creditor report as this is not posted to the 'Creditors Control Account'